# Nexus Repository Mangaer saves only assets but no components

Tags: npm, nexus

I've installed Nexus Repository Manager local on my machine. I want to use it with npm and I have followed all instructions given by the official documentation. However in the terminal I can see that npm is first looking at my proxy repo adress for the packeges. In the webtool I can see assets but no components are beeing saved. "No components found in repository". In sonatype-work\nexus3\db is no folder with name npm.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it. The checkbox for Nexus truststore wasn't checked. It has to be checked otherwise you wount be able to download packages.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpeP2.png)